# GDB: run with 2 commands

Tags: c, gdb

i am executing my program like this to give it some txt files as inputs

```
cat 1.txt 2.txt | ./myprogram
```

How can i run gdb with out entering manually all the txt files?

thnx <3

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
gdb ./myprogram

(gdb) run <(cat 1.txt 2.txt)
(gdb) run <(cat {1,2}.txt)
```

Or

```
gdb -ex 'run <(cat {1,2}.txt)' ./myprogram
```

Comment: @NickSt It works for me. Are you on Linux, Windows, or? Also, updating your question with *how* this answer doesn't work may get you a better one.

Comment: What version of gdb?